# Merge two dataframes based on partial startswith match

Tags: python, pandas, string, join, merge

I have two dataframe that I want to merge based on a partial match of start with (rows in df2.B that start with df1.A in the example below and the values of these columns are strings, which could be of any length).

I can do that the following way, but it is very slow on my actual dataframes, which have millions of rows each.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'cc']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['ar', 'd', 'ar'],
                    'C': ['x1', 'x1', 'x2']})

df_m = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C'])
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    df_ = df2[df2['B'].str.startswith(row['A'])]
    if not df_.empty:
        df_['A'] = row['A']
        df_m = df_m.append(df_)
```

df_m:

```
    A   B   C
0   a   ar  x1
2   a   ar  x2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use, [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to extract the `key` from the column B  in `df2` which starts with column A in `df1`, then use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to merge the datframe `df1` on `column A` and `df2` on column `key`:

```
key = df2['B'].str.extract('^(' + '|'.join(df1['A']) + ')')
df3 = df1.merge(df2.assign(key=key), left_on='A', right_on='key').drop('key', 1)
```

Result:

```
df3
   A   B   C
0  a  ar  x1
1  a  ar  x2
```

Comment: Ran it on a subset of my data and reduced runtime from 60s to 5s and outperforms the other solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We can do `findall` with `regex`

```
reg='^('+'|'.join(df1.A.tolist())+')'
df2['A']=df2.B.str.findall(reg).str[0]
df2
Out[60]: 
    B   C  A
0  ar  x1  a
1  ba  x1  b
2  ar  x2  a
```

Comment: "ba" is not one of the values of `df2.B`. I think my question needed more clarity. Added more details to the post.

Comment: @Reveille I am using ba for testing

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), you can do this:

```
df2[['l1','l2']] = pd.DataFrame(df2.B.apply(list).tolist(),index= df2.index)     
df_m = df1.merge(df2, left_on='A', right_on='l1').drop(['l1', 'l2'], 1)
```

Output:

```
In [70]: df_m 
Out[70]: 
   A   B   C
0  a  ar  x1
1  a  ar  x2
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get this error when I run it in the first line: `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`. my pd.__version__ 1.0.5